# Calculating SE, z, and p value in Cox PH model

Tags: cox-model

I am using cox proportional hazard models in R to test the effects of an environmental factor on survival. The data is such that I have two populations (P1 and P2). **I want to assess the effect of the factor on P1 and P2 individually and compare the effect on the two populations.**

The model output (see below) gives me several things..

- First of all, `PopulationP2` is the mortality risk of population P2 relative to P1: the difference is small and insignificant (coef = -0.026 ± 0.033, z = -0.78, p = 0.435), so I can conclude that the mortality risk does not differ between populations.
- Next it gives me the effect of `Factor`, and as I understand it this is on population P1. The factor decreases mortality risk in population P1 (coef = -0.185 ± 0.005, z = -34.98, p = <0.001).
- Finally it gives me the difference in the effect between population P1 and P2, `PopulationP2:Factor`, where there is no difference between the populations in the effect of the factor on mortality risk (-0.011 ± 0.007, z = -1.65, p = 0.098).

So this satisfies two of my three objectives, I can show and statistically test the effect of the factor on population P1 and test whether the two populations react differently. *However*, while I can derive the `coef` for population P2 (-0.18484 + -0.01142 = -0.19626), I have no formal test of whether this is significantly different from zero.

**How do I correctly estimate `coef`, `exp(coef)`, `se(coef)`, `z` and `p` values for population P2 from this model?**

---

Here's the R script:

```
> coxdata = data.frame(
+     "Population" = sample(c("P1","P2"), size = 5000, replace = T), 
+     "Factor" = rnorm(5000,0,5), 
+     "Status" = sample(c(1,2,2,2), size = 5000, replace = T), 
+     "Life" = rnorm(5000, 50, 5))
> head(coxdata)
  Population    Factor Status     Life
1         P1  3.605146      2 56.26822
2         P2 -0.617696      1 54.54506
3         P2 -2.598674      2 49.93539
4         P2  3.484734      2 48.46286
5         P1 -2.195290      1 48.05544
6         P2 -7.370659      1 52.61020
> 
> coxdata$Life = coxdata$Life+coxdata$Factor
> 
> coxdata$SurvObj = with(coxdata, Surv(Life, Status == 2))
> coxmodel = coxph(SurvObj ~ Population*Factor, data = coxdata)
> coxmodel
Call:
coxph(formula = SurvObj ~ Population * Factor, data = coxdata)


                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
PopulationP2        -0.02552   0.97480  0.03271  -0.78  0.435
Factor              -0.18484   0.83124  0.00528 -34.98 <2e-16
PopulationP2:Factor -0.01142   0.98865  0.00690  -1.65  0.098

Likelihood ratio test=2249  on 3 df, p=0
n= 5000, number of events= 3750
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand the question, there should not be any difference. The two categories are complimentary. If P1's coefficient is `-0.02552`, than P1's coefficient will be `(+)0.02552`, and the `exp(coef)` will be complementary also. The interaction should be the same with a flipped sign. This really makes sense because they are constantly compared to each other. By how much am I taller than my wife? `20cm`, by how much is my wife taller than me? `-20cm`. The significance level will be the same.

Case in point - lets switch the reference category on the `Population` covariate and compare the models.

> Note - I could not duplicate your model since the seed was random. Here I use `set.seed(1000)`

First we try with the reference as P1:

```html
> coxmodel
Call:
coxph(formula = SurvObj ~ Population * Factor, data = coxdata)

                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
PopulationP1         0.03701   1.03770  0.03271   1.13   0.26
Factor              -0.20429   0.81522  0.00549 -37.19 <2e-16
PopulationP1:Factor  0.01289   1.01297  0.00684   1.88   0.06
```

Now we will change the reference category to P2 (using the `relevel()` function):

```html
coxdata <- within(coxdata, Population <- relevel(Population, ref = 2))
coxmodel = coxph(SurvObj ~ Population*Factor, data = coxdata)
> coxmodel
Call:
coxph(formula = SurvObj ~ Population * Factor, data = coxdata)

                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
PopulationP2        -0.03701   0.96367  0.03271  -1.13   0.26
Factor              -0.19140   0.82580  0.00520 -36.83 <2e-16
PopulationP2:Factor -0.01289   0.98719  0.00684  -1.88   0.06
```

:)

Comment: @rg255 did this help?